# RecycleView + CardView in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to use recycleView + cardView in fragment for my android studio project. When I run the app, it's forced closed. Can someone tells me how to solve this issue?

[image: logcat]

my code
fragment_home.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="20sp"
                android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/news"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help me for this issue.

Comment: Can you post the error log? Or Are you getting the title data correctly or is there any null pointer exception?

Comment: What's the error shown in Logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have recyclerview with id: "dataList" in your fragment's xml: "fragment_home". The error is telling you that there is something wrong with your recyclerview initialization and thus it is null and you are trying to call setLayoutManager() from a null object reference.

Comment: I forget to remark setLayoutManager, because i cannot use it, but still error

Comment: Please post the fragment xml.

Comment: That is my fragment.xml

Comment: there is no recyclerview in your fragment "fragment_home", you need to define your recyclerview there and give it the id "dataList".

Comment: The issue is solved, thank u for your help